# Kotlin anonymous object inheriting from base class but keeping derived class properties

Tags: object, kotlin, inheritance

I have a problem that I am not quire sure how to figure out elegantly:

```
abstract class BaseContinuousSingleObjectiveFitnessFunction {

    // Invoke should compute some function, like f(x) = x^2 + 3x + 5
    abstract fun invoke(x: List<Double>): Double

    // This is supposed to take a function that will be called on the result of invoke
    // and return an object derived from this one that has its invoke overriden to call
    // the new function on the result of the original one.
    fun modify(f: (Double) -> Double): BaseContinuousSingleObjectiveFitnessFunction {
        val originalFunction = this
        return object : BaseContinuousSingleObjectiveFitnessFunction() {
            override operator fun invoke(x: List<Double>): Double = f(originalFunction(x))
        }
    }
}
```

Now, this works, but `modify` does not preserve the properties of the derived types.

So for example lets say I add this to the project:

```
class XTimesA(val a: Double): BaseContinuousSingleObjectiveFitnessFunction() {
    override operator fun invoke(x: List<Double>) = x.sumByDouble { a*it }
}
```

Then I want to call modify on it:

```
val f1 = XTimesA(a = 5.0)
println(f1.a) // Works

val f2 = f1.modify { it.pow(2) }
println(f2.a) // This fails because it is not recognized as deriving XTimesA
```

Is there a way to not copy-paste `modify` into every deriving class but still keep access to the properties?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to access the property value on all inheritance levels, you have to lift the property up to the base class:

```
abstract class BaseContinuousSingleObjectiveFitnessFunction<Value>(val value: Value) {

    abstract fun invoke(x: List<Value>): Value

    fun modify(f: (Value) -> Value): BaseContinuousSingleObjectiveFitnessFunction<Value> {
        val originalFunction = this
        return object : BaseContinuousSingleObjectiveFitnessFunction<Value>() {
            override operator fun invoke(x: List<Value>): Value = f(originalFunction(x))
        }
    }
}
```

`Value` is a generic type here for the case that `Double` is not applicable in all cases. If all values are of type Double than the class wouldn't need this type parameter.

Comment: But what if other classes do not have that property? `XTimesA` has an `a`, then maybe another class has a `alpha` and `beta`, etc. basically what if the properties are not really liftable because they are highly specific to the classes implementing them.

Comment: The compromise is to unify the name of the property. If you can not unify it or don't want to, then I don't see an elegant solution. To do it, Kotlin would need [self-types](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/self-types.html), I think.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [F-bounded polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_quantification#F-bounded_quantification) for this. Something like

```
abstract class BaseContinuousSingleObjectiveFitnessFunction<T : BaseContinuousSingleObjectiveFitnessFunction<T>> {

    // Invoke should compute some function, like f(x) = x^2 + 3x + 5
    abstract operator fun invoke(x: List<Double>): Double

    abstract fun construct(f: (List<Double>) -> Double): T

    // This is supposed to take a function that will be called on the result of invoke
    // and return an object derived from this one that has its invoke overriden to call
    // the new function on the result of the original one.
    fun modify(f: (Double) -> Double): T = construct { list -> f(this(x)) } 
}

open class XTimesA(val a: Double): BaseContinuousSingleObjectiveFitnessFunction<XTimesA>() {
    override operator fun invoke(x: List<Double>) = x.sumByDouble { a*it }

    override fun construct(f: (List<Double>) -> Double) = object : XTimesA(a) {
        override operator fun invoke(x: List<Double>) = f(x)
    }
}
```

However, in this particular case I don't think it actually makes sense and your example shows why: `f1.modify { it.pow(2) }` represents the function `x -> x.sumByDouble { 5 * it }.pow(2)` which isn't `x -> x.sumByDouble { a * it }` for any `a`!

Comment: Thanks! The example is very simplistic because it would make no sense to use the catual function I am using in my project, which is much more complex. These modification are just examples of more complex ones used to reverse convexities or enforce limits, sorry if the example was bad!